# word replacement within a string

Tags: java, regex, string, delimiter

I need help creating a loop which will return a string, replacing the words in it that are surrounded by hashmarks by using predefined operations.  These include getRandomElement, getPhrases, and replace and all belong to the class "parserHelperImpl."  The code I've written thus far is below.  In a separate class is the code used in this parserHelperImpl class.  Specifically where I'm stuck is creating something to move through the random phrase, here named "archetype," and locate words surrounded by hashmarks.  Documentation on regex is a bit above my level to digest.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;


public class PhraseGeneratorFromFile implements PhraseGenerator {

    private ParserHelperImpl parserHelper;

    public PhraseGeneratorFromFile(String filename) {
        // read file
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("corporate.txt"));
        try {

            String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                fileContent.append(line);
                fileContent.append('\n');
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String everything = fileContent.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }


        parserHelper = new ParserHelperImpl();


        List<String> phraseCollection = parserHelper.getPhrases(fileContent,"phrases:");
        String archetype = parserHelper.getRandomElement(phraseCollection);

    }


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class ParserHelperImpl implements ParserHelper{

    @Override
    public List<String> getPhrases(StringBuilder fileContent, String token) {
          StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(fileContent.toString()));
          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          try {
            while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
                if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
                  tokenizer.nextToken();  // '[' 
                  do {
                    tokenizer.nextToken();  // go to the number
                    list.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.sval));
                  } while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');
                  break;
                }
              }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
          return list;
        }

    @Override
    public String replace(String templatePhrase, String token, String wordToPut) {
        return templatePhrase.replace(token, wordToPut);
    }

    @Override
    public String getRandomElement(List<String> list) {
        double randnum = Math.random() * list.size();
        int randindex = (int) randnum;
        return list.get(randindex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regex like this `#[^#]+#` to find the words surrounded by hash marks. Iterate over the matches and replace each of them... presumably you have to call `getRandomElement` to get the replacement word.

Comment: How do I work with pieces on the level of words in a string without turning the string into an array?  I know about the charAt method, but I need some way to work with this regex.  Should I be thinking in terms of subString?